# How to get notification and received address, amount from it from altcoin daemon?

Tags: javascript, typescript, blockchain, cryptocurrency

Now I hosted an altcoin daemon forked from PIVX.
It has a bunch of addresses and users can send coins to one of the addresses.
I wanna set up a notification system so that once someone sends coins to the wallet, it notifies me. And also I wanna get received address and amount from the notification.
How to set up this notification system and archive the goal?
I'm trying to write the code in Typescript or Javascript.